# Stitching images to create a montage

Tags: osx, image-processing, image-editor

Currently I'm using [this](https://github.com/adrienverge/PhotoCollage) application to create a photo montage for various galleries, however the app does not build correctly on OSX.

I'm looking for an OSX equivalent to do the same thing.

Requirements
- Must be able to stitch 100+ photos
- Max width parameter
- Must be able to deal with different sized images in a 'masonry' way

The following is also acceptable:

- command line apps
- photoshop plugin
- must be < $100

Screenshot attached of sample output

[image]

Comment: If this is just for putting on a website, why not put all the images inside an unsorted list, and set a width on the container, and set a height on the images? This will allow you to link the images to their respective larger images.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) from the command line with its `montage` command there are lots  of options available to play with.

- It runs on Linux, Windows, Mac Os X, iOS, Android OS, and others.
- Lots of other options and operations
- Fast - uses multiple cores/threads.
- Can handle lots of images, (tip you can resize images as you load them), read, process, or write mega-, giga-, or tera-pixel image sizes.
- Can handle lots of file formats, (over 200), even most RAW formats
- < $100 - Yes it is **free!**
- Montage in a masonry way - it might take a little playing with the options and reading the online examples but I am sure that you can achieve what you need.

If all else fails you can divide your selected montage into sections by size, montage the components that you need into each and then montage or collate them together.  Another method is to use a dummy, 100% transparent, element of each size to reserve the places for the other bits then use the overlay method to join them together:

If a are small images, t are an equal size transparent and B is a Big Image 4 times the size and T a transparent that size, then
aaaaaaaa     TT
aaaaaaaa  +  TT
aaaatttt     TB
aaaatttt     TB

should give you what you need.

Comment: I am aware of montage but I wasn't aware that it could provide a masonry grid like so - http://printingcode.runemadsen.com/assets/grid/random_grid_small-353d03223020c36ab051a436ca94863f.jpg - I'll play around this evening.